# Am I not returning a string?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, for-loop, return

I'm writing a method to find the upper case letters in a given string. I have this

```
public static String FindUpperCase (String x){
 for (int i = x.length(); i>=0; i--){
      if (Character.isUpperCase(x.charAt(i))){
          return x.substring(i); }
    }
```

But I'm getting an error thats telling me I must return a string. When I look up on the API what substring does it tells me that it returns a string that is a subset of the other string...which means I am returning a string, right? I was told that it was because I am returning a string within the loop and that's not the same thing but I'm a little confused by what this means because isn't the loop in the method? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or how I can fix this?

Comment: It's complaining because you're not (yet) returning a string if the `if` statement always evaluates to `false`.

Comment: Your code returns a string only when it enters the IF condition. What if the IF is never executed?

Comment: By "find uppercase letters" do you mean "portion of string after first upper case letter"?

Comment: *All* execution paths must return a string.

Comment: I would like to know why the downvotes to the question, just to be clear

Comment: For downvotes, my guess is that that if you look at the actual error it will say that at the *end of the method* there is no String returned. I suspect reading the error carefully will reveal the problem.  In my IDE and compiler it clearly shows the last line, the last `}` is the issue, not the line the OP is questioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're not always returning a string. What if the input is entirely lower case?

Basically, you need a `return` statement (or throw an exception) *after* the `for` loop, to handle the situation where you get to the end of it. Even in cases that *you* can reason that you'll never actually get to the end of the loop, the Java compiler follows strict rules for reachability, as specified in [section 14.21 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21). So even if your return statement were unconditional and *we* know that `length()` always returns a non-negative value, this still wouldn't compile:

```
public static String broken(String input) {
    // *We* know that we'll always go into the body of the loop...
    for (int x = input.length(); x >= 0; x--) {
        return input;
    }
    // The end of the method is still reachable from the compiler's standpoint
}
```

The end of a non-void method can't be reachable - you *must* either throw an exception or return a value.

Also note that your initial value should be `x.length() - 1` or `x.charAt(i)` will throw an exception. You should also change your method name to follow Java naming conventions.

Oh, and currently you're not returning "the upper case letters" - you're returning "everything from the last upper case character onwards" which is entirely different.

Comment: What! No! You need a `return ''` after the for loop!

Comment: So fast, I ended up deleting my answer.

Comment: @Brian WUT? `''` is not a `String`.

Comment: @Brian: You need *some* kind of `return` statement or `throw` statement. There's no indication that it should return an empty string (and even if it should, `return '';` would be invalid Java).

Answer (score 2):

You are returning subjected to a condition, so if the condition is never `true` you are not returning. Try instead.

```
public static String FindUpperCase (String x){
    for (int i = x.length() - 1; i>=0; i--){
        if (Character.isUpperCase(x.charAt(i))){
            return x.substring(i); }
    return "";
}
```

Also Java is indexes start at 0, so your `for` sentence starts at `x.length() - 1` (last position) or you will get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case when there's no uppercase in the given string, in that case, the function won't return anything.

So just after your `for` loop, you can return an empty string to make the function declaration valid.

Answer (score 1):

Because you return string only if `Character.isUpperCase(x.charAt(i))` is true. You have to return for example empty string if it is false.

```
public static String FindUpperCase (String x){
   for (int i = x.length(); i>=0; i--){
      if (Character.isUpperCase(x.charAt(i))){
         return x.substring(i); }
   }
   return "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that you are returning a string dependend on an if statement. You have to return a string or null in every possible case. Just place a `return null` or return `""` at the last line of the function for a quick and dirty solution. Better would be to think what you want to return if no uppercase character is found.